# is there any way to apply formmatter to all column or whole table?

Tags: c#, html, tabulator

```
var table = new Tabulator("#Mytable",
    {        
        layout:"fitColumns", 
       columns: [
           { title: "Name",formatter:html, variableHeight:true},
           { title: "Ingredients in1 L" ,formatter:html, variableHeight:true},
           { title: "Type of solution",formatter:html, variableHeight:true},
           { title: "pH",formatter:html, variableHeight:true},//"html" }
           { title: "Normal osmolarity (240‐340 mOsm/L)",formatter:htmlWrapFormatter, variableHeight:true},//"html" }
        ]
    });
```

Inside column[] is there any way to apply the same attribute property without specifying the column name.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

```
http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/modules#default
```

It provides a method to provide default setup options.